# Can't finalize the function Camel Case

Tags: javascript

I can't understand where is first word on output..

```
function camelCase(str){

let string = '';
let arr = str.split(' ');
let oneStr = '';
let twoStr = '';
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
string1 = arr[i] ;

oneStr = string1[0].toUpperCase() + string1.slice(1);

}

return oneStr;
}

console.log(camelCase('camel case'));
```

Output: Case

Help please to finalize the code

Comment: On looping, you're replacing the first element with the second element. Due to which you're losing camel.

Comment: that's right, yes, tnx

Answer (score 3):

On this line, use `+=` operator to concatenate the strings:

```
oneStr += string1[0].toUpperCase() + string1.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you assigned the result to `string1` in each iteration, instead use +=  operator

```js
function camelCase(str){

let string = '';
let arr = str.split(' ');
let oneStr = '';
let twoStr = '';
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
string1 = arr[i] ;

oneStr += string1[0].toUpperCase() + string1.slice(1);

}

return oneStr;
}

console.log(camelCase('camel case'));
```